# Error while creating a Redis object and executing commands when calling methods

Tags: redis, redis-cache

This is the output of my rails console after I include rubygems and redis.

```
2.0.0-p353 :024 > r = Redis.new
=> #<Redis client v3.0.7 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0> 
2.0.0-p353 :025 > r.set('foo','bar')
=> "OK" 
2.0.0-p353 :026 > r.get('foo')
=> "bar"
2.0.0-p353 :033 > r.lpush('foo','bar')
Redis::CommandError: ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:97:in `call'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:949:in `block in lpush'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:37:in `block in synchronize'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:37:in `synchronize'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:948:in `lpush'
from (irb):33
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p353 :034 > r.lpush(foo,'bar')
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
from (irb):34
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/poorva/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** the first argument has to the first argument of the lpush command, that is to say the key of the list. and the second, the value to be pushed.

---

initial message (before the question was modified)

The message is explicit `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`. Just give LPUSH the expected arguments as described in [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands/lpush) : the key and the value to be pushed.

```
lpush('mylist', 'bar')
```

Comment: i had just printed the output r.lpush to show that  method lpush exists. I knew it needs 2 arguments.Please read the logs carefully.

Comment: Update: the 'foo' and 'bar' value in my previous answer were just example, you should not have taken them literally :(. I updated my answer.

Comment: r.lpush('boo','bar') gave me error was the problem. Later i checked in
http://redis.io/topics/quickstart i had to install gem SystemTimer due to which i was getting an error - NameError: undefined local variable or method `boo' for main:Object